# Database query tool for Mac OS X?

Tags: sql, macos, odbc

I need to test one odbc driver for mac.
What are database query utilities using ODBC for Mac OS X like DBForge, OmniDB etc?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are testing a driver bound to iODBC, the ODBC driver manager that Apple ships with macOS, you should install the [latest iODBC SDK update](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/Downloads#Mac%20OS%20X), which comes with `iODBC Test.command` and `iODBC Demo.app` (found in `/Applications/iODBC/`).  You can execute any arbitrary ODBC query through these tools.

[ODBC Bench](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/ODBCBench), a separate install which simulates TPC-A and TPC-C on your own equipment/network. (You'll need to build your own binary to test a 64-bit driver, as the downloadable pre-built binary is 32-bit only.)

Most GUI-space apps on macOS are shipped with binding to iODBC, and are thus also candidates for your use.